# selection based on percentage weighting

Tags: c#, python, algorithm, random

I have a set of values, and an associated percentage for each:

a: 70% chance
b: 20% chance
c: 10% chance

I want to select a value (a, b, c) based on the percentage chance given.

how do I approach this?

my attempt so far looks like this:

```
r = random.random()
if r <= .7:
    return a
elif r <= .9:
    return b
else: 
    return c
```

I'm stuck coming up with an algorithm to handle this.  How should I approach this so it can handle larger sets of values without just chaining together if-else flows.

(any explanation or answers in pseudo-code are fine.  a python or C# implementation would be especially helpful)

Comment: I had this problem and ended up building a library: https://github.com/kinetiq/Ether.WeightedSelector

Comment: Very nice and simple implementation in c# here:
http://www.vcskicks.com/random-element.php

Answer (score 38):

**Here is a complete solution in C#:**

```
public class ProportionValue<T>
{
    public double Proportion { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public static class ProportionValue
{
    public static ProportionValue<T> Create<T>(double proportion, T value)
    {
        return new ProportionValue<T> { Proportion = proportion, Value = value };
    }

    static Random random = new Random();
    public static T ChooseByRandom<T>(
        this IEnumerable<ProportionValue<T>> collection)
    {
        var rnd = random.NextDouble();
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (rnd < item.Proportion)
                return item.Value;
            rnd -= item.Proportion;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "The proportions in the collection do not add up to 1.");
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var list = new[] {
    ProportionValue.Create(0.7, "a"),
    ProportionValue.Create(0.2, "b"),
    ProportionValue.Create(0.1, "c")
};

// Outputs "a" with probability 0.7, etc.
Console.WriteLine(list.ChooseByRandom());
```

Comment: Got an error, had to change ChooseByRandom definition to: `public static T ChooseByRandom<T>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProportionValue<T>> collection)`

Comment: Also, it would be neat if this could take any value, not just 0.3 etc. It should add up all values and calculate the percentage on its own so the users don't have to care about that. Like values 400 and 1600 would end up as 0.2 and 0.8 etc.

Comment: @Jonny Your second suggestion is (very) easy to do: 1) Make a version of the function that receives a map of values, have the map's keys be the chances. 2) Sum the value of all keys (chances). In your example, 2000. 3) Divide each key (chance) by the total, and the result will be the proportion of that key in relation to the total, between 0 and 1. In this case, just like your example, 0.2, and 0.8.

Comment: @Timwi could you please tell whats this algorithm name is?

Comment: Nice, it is important to mention that the solution above isn't a thread-safe approach.

Answer (score 9):

For Python:

```
>>> import random
>>> dst = 70, 20, 10
>>> vls = 'a', 'b', 'c'
>>> picks = [v for v, d in zip(vls, dst) for _ in range(d)]
>>> for _ in range(12): print random.choice(picks),
... 
a c c b a a a a a a a a
>>> for _ in range(12): print random.choice(picks),
... 
a c a c a b b b a a a a
>>> for _ in range(12): print random.choice(picks),
... 
a a a a c c a c a a c a
>>>
```

General idea: make a list where each item is repeated a number of times proportional to the probability it should have; use `random.choice` to pick one at random (uniformly), this will match your required probability distribution.  Can be a bit wasteful of memory if your probabilities are expressed in peculiar ways (e.g., `70, 20, 10` makes a 100-items list where `7, 2, 1` would make a list of just 10 items with exactly the same behavior), but you could divide all the counts in the probabilities list by their greatest common factor if you think that's likely to be a big deal in your specific application scenario.

Apart from memory consumption issues, this should be the fastest solution -- just one random number generation per required output result, and the fastest possible lookup from that random number, no comparisons &c.  If your likely probabilities are very weird (e.g., floating point numbers that need to be matched to many, many significant digits), other approaches may be preferable;-).

Comment: Hm, I’m not sure about the performance characteristics of creating a list of hundreds of entries when only three are required.

Comment: This works OK (but not optimal) when the percentages are all integers, but what if they're arbitrary real numbers? There are better solutions.

Comment: @Timwi, have you _measured_?  The list being created once, and then many random numbers being generated from it, you might be surprised how well this performs.  @Mark, I did say this is not optimal if you are given floats so incredibly precise that you need to match many digits of them in your expected probability distribution (not a sensible spec, mind you, but then, whoever's specifying and paying for the code is not always a sensible person, especially when they're paying with other people's money...;-).  The OP says "percentages" and those are often rounded to the nearest percent, ya'know?

Comment: @Alex, you're absolutely right, this does meet the spec. It's also very easy to understand once you decipher the `picks` generator. I just find it hard to recommend a limited solution when a more general one is nearly as simple.

Comment: @Mark, my code, when made into a function, is actually simpler than yours -- and _performance_ is potentially quite a bit better, when the conditions are met.  The "picks generator" (which isn't one -- it's a list comprehension) can of course easily be refactored into a loop -- it's a _preliminary_ anyway (not executed on _every_ call, only on those where the desired probabilities _change_) so the listcomp's or loop's performance is probably going to be amortized away in any normal, useful, sensible case.

Comment: @Alex, you've convinced me. And sorry for my imprecise terminology.

Comment: @Mark, absolutely NP -- great to see you're such a reasonable person as to care about the discussion, tx!

Comment: For fractional probabilities just multiply out where possible. e.g. 32.443% --> 32443.  If you go to 0.001% precision that's only a 100k list which is not a big deal.  For all the problems I deal with 0.001% is plenty of precision.  Great solution, thx.

Answer (score 8):

Knuth references Walker's method of aliases. Searching on this, I find http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576564-walkers-alias-method-for-random-objects-with-diffe/ and http://prxq.wordpress.com/2006/04/17/the-alias-method/. This gives the exact probabilities required in constant time per number generated with linear time for setup (curiously, n log n time for setup if you use exactly the method Knuth describes, which does a preparatory sort you can avoid).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027757/data-structure-for-loaded-dice - this is also known as Vose's alias method, due to [this](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~vose/Publications/random.pdf) improvement to (the startup time of) the method.

Answer (score 6):

Take the list of and find the cumulative total of the weights: 70, 70+20, 70+20+10.  Pick a random number greater than or equal to zero and less than the total.  Iterate over the items and return the first value for which the cumulative sum of the weights is greater than this random number:

```
def select( values ):
    variate = random.random() * sum( values.values() )
    cumulative = 0.0
    for item, weight in values.items():
        cumulative += weight
        if variate < cumulative:
            return item
    return item # Shouldn't get here, but just in case of rounding...

print select( { "a": 70, "b": 20, "c": 10 } )
```

This solution, as implemented, should also be able to handle fractional weights and weights that add up to any number so long as they're all non-negative.

Comment: When I first saw this answer it didn't have any code in it. Looks like we were busy coming up with essentially the same code at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

1. Let T = the sum of all item weights
2. Let R = a random number between 0 and T
3. Iterate the item list subtracting each item weight from R and return the item that causes the result to become <= 0.

Comment: +1 because in my version, I was sorting the list first and then iterating, and you made me realize that's not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
def weighted_choice(probabilities):
    random_position = random.random() * sum(probabilities)
    current_position = 0.0
    for i, p in enumerate(probabilities):
        current_position += p
        if random_position < current_position:
            return i
    return None
```

Because `random.random` will always return < 1.0, the final `return` should never be reached.

Comment: Note to reader: `sum(probabilities)` is not necessary if your distribution is normalized. This code also correctly will not return choices with a probability of 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

def selector(weights):
    i=random.random()*sum(x for x,y in weights)
    for w,v in weights:
        if w>=i:
            break
        i-=w
    return v

weights = ((70,'a'),(20,'b'),(10,'c'))
print [selector(weights) for x in range(10)]
```

it works equally well for fractional weights

```
weights = ((0.7,'a'),(0.2,'b'),(0.1,'c'))
print [selector(weights) for x in range(10)]
```

If you have a *lot* of weights, you can use bisect to reduce the number of iterations required

```
import random
import bisect

def make_acc_weights(weights):
    acc=0
    acc_weights = []
    for w,v in weights:
        acc+=w
        acc_weights.append((acc,v))
    return acc_weights

def selector(acc_weights):
    i=random.random()*sum(x for x,y in weights)
    return weights[bisect.bisect(acc_weights, (i,))][1]

weights = ((70,'a'),(20,'b'),(10,'c'))
acc_weights = make_acc_weights(weights)    
print [selector(acc_weights) for x in range(100)]
```

Also works fine for fractional weights

```
weights = ((0.7,'a'),(0.2,'b'),(0.1,'c'))
acc_weights = make_acc_weights(weights)    
print [selector(acc_weights) for x in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 2):

today, [the update of python document](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/random.html#examples-and-recipes) give an example to make a random.choice() with weighted probabilities:

If the weights are small integer ratios, a simple technique is to build a sample population with repeats:

```
>>> weighted_choices = [('Red', 3), ('Blue', 2), ('Yellow', 1), ('Green', 4)]
>>> population = [val for val, cnt in weighted_choices for i in range(cnt)]
>>> random.choice(population)
'Green'
```

A more general approach is to arrange the weights in a cumulative distribution with itertools.accumulate(), and then locate the random value with bisect.bisect():

```
>>> choices, weights = zip(*weighted_choices)
>>> cumdist = list(itertools.accumulate(weights))
>>> x = random.random() * cumdist[-1]
>>> choices[bisect.bisect(cumdist, x)]
'Blue'
```

one note: [itertools.accumulate() needs python 3.2 or define it with the Equivalent.](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have an array of small objects (I implemented in Java although I know a little bit C# but I am afraid can write wrong code), so you may need to port it yourself. The code in C# will be much smaller with struct, var but I hope you get the idea

```
class PercentString {
  double percent;
  String value;
  // Constructor for 2 values
}

ArrayList<PercentString> list = new ArrayList<PercentString();
list.add(new PercentString(70, "a");
list.add(new PercentString(20, "b");
list.add(new PercentString(10, "c");

double percent = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  PercentString p = list.get(i);
  percent += p.percent;
  if (random < percent) {
    return p.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the requirement, I changed my code

Comment: where is your `random` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

If you are really up to speed and want to generate the random values quickly, the Walker's algorithm mcdowella mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655773/1212517 is pretty much the best way to go (O(1) time for random(), and O(N) time for preprocess()).

For anyone who is interested, here is my own PHP implementation of the algorithm:

```
/**
 * Pre-process the samples (Walker's alias method).
 * @param array key represents the sample, value is the weight
 */
protected function preprocess($weights){

    $N = count($weights);
    $sum = array_sum($weights);
    $avg = $sum / (double)$N;

    //divide the array of weights to values smaller and geq than sum/N 
    $smaller = array_filter($weights, function($itm) use ($avg){ return $avg > $itm;}); $sN = count($smaller); 
    $greater_eq = array_filter($weights, function($itm) use ($avg){ return $avg <= $itm;}); $gN = count($greater_eq);

    $bin = array(); //bins

    //we want to fill N bins
    for($i = 0;$i<$N;$i++){
        //At first, decide for a first value in this bin
        //if there are small intervals left, we choose one
        if($sN > 0){  
            $choice1 = each($smaller); 
            unset($smaller[$choice1['key']]);
            $sN--;
        } else{  //otherwise, we split a large interval
            $choice1 = each($greater_eq); 
            unset($greater_eq[$choice1['key']]);
        }

        //splitting happens here - the unused part of interval is thrown back to the array
        if($choice1['value'] >= $avg){
            if($choice1['value'] - $avg >= $avg){
                $greater_eq[$choice1['key']] = $choice1['value'] - $avg;
            }else if($choice1['value'] - $avg > 0){
                $smaller[$choice1['key']] = $choice1['value'] - $avg;
                $sN++;
            }
            //this bin comprises of only one value
            $bin[] = array(1=>$choice1['key'], 2=>null, 'p1'=>1, 'p2'=>0);
        }else{
            //make the second choice for the current bin
            $choice2 = each($greater_eq);
            unset($greater_eq[$choice2['key']]);

            //splitting on the second interval
            if($choice2['value'] - $avg + $choice1['value'] >= $avg){
                $greater_eq[$choice2['key']] = $choice2['value'] - $avg + $choice1['value'];
            }else{
                $smaller[$choice2['key']] = $choice2['value'] - $avg + $choice1['value'];
                $sN++;
            }

            //this bin comprises of two values
            $choice2['value'] = $avg - $choice1['value'];
            $bin[] = array(1=>$choice1['key'], 2=>$choice2['key'],
                           'p1'=>$choice1['value'] / $avg, 
                           'p2'=>$choice2['value'] / $avg);
        }
    }

    $this->bins = $bin;
}

/**
 * Choose a random sample according to the weights.
 */
public function random(){
    $bin = $this->bins[array_rand($this->bins)];
    $randValue = (lcg_value() < $bin['p1'])?$bin[1]:$bin[2];        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version that can apply to any `IList` and normalize the weight. It is based on Timwi's solution : [selection based on percentage weighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655430/selection-based-on-percentage-weighting/3655534#3655534)

```
/// <summary>
/// return a random element of the list or default if list is empty
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e"></param>
/// <param name="weightSelector">
/// return chances to be picked for the element. A weigh of 0 or less means 0 chance to be picked.
/// If all elements have weight of 0 or less they all have equal chances to be picked.
/// </param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static T AnyOrDefault<T>(this IList<T> e, Func<T, double> weightSelector)
{
    if (e.Count < 1)
        return default(T);
    if (e.Count == 1)
        return e[0];
    var weights = e.Select(o => Math.Max(weightSelector(o), 0)).ToArray();
    var sum = weights.Sum(d => d);

    var rnd = new Random().NextDouble();
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.Length; i++)
    {
        //Normalize weight
        var w = sum == 0
            ? 1 / (double)e.Count
            : weights[i] / sum;
        if (rnd < w)
            return e[i];
        rnd -= w;
    }
    throw new Exception("Should not happen");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've my own solution for this:

```
public class Randomizator3000 
{    
public class Item<T>
{
    public T value;
    public float weight;

    public static float GetTotalWeight<T>(Item<T>[] p_itens)
    {
        float __toReturn = 0;
        foreach(var item in p_itens)
        {
            __toReturn += item.weight;
        }

        return __toReturn;
    }
}

private static System.Random _randHolder;
private static System.Random _random
{
    get 
    {
        if(_randHolder == null)
            _randHolder = new System.Random();

        return _randHolder;
    }
}

public static T PickOne<T>(Item<T>[] p_itens)
{   
    if(p_itens == null || p_itens.Length == 0)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    float __randomizedValue = (float)_random.NextDouble() * (Item<T>.GetTotalWeight(p_itens));
    float __adding = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < p_itens.Length; i ++)
    {
        float __cacheValue = p_itens[i].weight + __adding;
        if(__randomizedValue <= __cacheValue)
        {
            return p_itens[i].value;
        }

        __adding = __cacheValue;
    }

    return p_itens[p_itens.Length - 1].value;

}
}
```

And using it should be something like that (thats in Unity3d)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class teste : MonoBehaviour 
{
Randomizator3000.Item<string>[] lista;

void Start()
{
    lista = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>[10];
    lista[0] = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>();
    lista[0].weight = 10;
    lista[0].value = "a";

    lista[1] = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>();
    lista[1].weight = 10;
    lista[1].value = "b";

    lista[2] = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>();
    lista[2].weight = 10;
    lista[2].value = "c";

    lista[3] = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>();
    lista[3].weight = 10;
    lista[3].value = "d";

    lista[4] = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>();
    lista[4].weight = 10;
    lista[4].value = "e";

    lista[5] = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>();
    lista[5].weight = 10;
    lista[5].value = "f";

    lista[6] = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>();
    lista[6].weight = 10;
    lista[6].value = "g";

    lista[7] = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>();
    lista[7].weight = 10;
    lista[7].value = "h";

    lista[8] = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>();
    lista[8].weight = 10;
    lista[8].value = "i";

    lista[9] = new Randomizator3000.Item<string>();
    lista[9].weight = 10;
    lista[9].value = "j";
}


void Update () 
{
    Debug.Log(Randomizator3000.PickOne<string>(lista));
}
}
```

In this example each value has a 10% chance do be displayed as a debug =3

Answer (score 0):

Based loosely on python's `numpy.random.choice(a=items, p=probs)`, which takes an array and a probability array of the same size.

```
    public T RandomChoice<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<double> p)
    {
        IEnumerator<T> ae = a.GetEnumerator();
        Random random = new Random();
        double target = random.NextDouble();
        double accumulator = 0;
        foreach (var prob in p)
        {
            ae.MoveNext();
            accumulator += prob;
            if (accumulator > target)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return ae.Current;
    }
```

The probability array `p` must sum to (approx.) 1.  This is to keep it consistent with the numpy interface (and mathematics), but you could easily change that if you wanted.