# Random non-uniform distribution with given proportion

Tags: python, non-uniform-distribution

I have 3 labels: "A","B","C".

I want to generate a random list with 100 elements, 60% of them are "A", 30% are "B", 10% are "C".

How can I do this? (I am new in python, hope this question is not too silly.)

---

Edit: 
My question is slightly different from this question:
[Generate random numbers with a given (numerical) distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution)

Just like in the comment, I want exactly 60% of them are "A", not every element has a 60% probability to be "A". So the numpy.random.choice() is not the solution for me.

Comment: Thats not really random then is it?

Comment: random with given distribution: ABAAACBAAAB

Comment: Ah! That makes more sense.

Comment: You need to clarify if you mean that *exactly* 60 of them will be A, and so you simply need to build a list and shuffle it, or if you want each element to have a 60% *chance* of being A (and so sometimes you'll get 65 As, sometimes 45 As, very rarely 5 As, and so on.)

Comment: Maybe some of the answers here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265988/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-numerical-distribution

Comment: @DSM Thanks for the answer! I mean actually the first case. But if I also want to do with the second case, what shall I do?

Comment: @marsh it is random, just **non-uniform**

Comment: @xirururu: do you just want the case where the proportions are (small) integers, or the genera case where they're arbitrary real numbers? Anyway, people have given you both.

Comment: related: [Weighted random sample in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13052108/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want *exactly* 60% to be A, 30% B and 10% C and you know there have to be 100 elements in total, you can do something like the following:

```
import random

num = 100
prob_a = 0.6
prob_b = 0.3
prob_c = 0.1

As = int(num*prob_a) * 'A'
Bs = int(num*prob_b) * 'B'
Cs = int(num*prob_c) * 'C'

# create a list with 60 As, 30 Bs, and 10 Cs
chars = list(As + Bs + Cs)
random.shuffle(chars)

print("".join(chars))
```

That'll output something like `BAAAAABBCBAABABAAAACAABBAABACAACBAACBBBAAACBAAAABAAABABAAAAABBBABAABAABAACCAABABAAAAAACABBBBCABAAAAA`

Comment: I updated it because the old version didn't really work (was multiplying a float by a string).

Answer (score 6):

You can just permute a list. Lets say you create the list

```
x = list('A'*60 + 'B'*30 + 'C'*10)
```

Then, you can shuffle this *in-place* like so:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like that if distributions should be uniform, A will *on average* occur in 60% of cases, and so other values

```
import random
res = []
for i in range(0, n_samples):
   r = random.random()
   if(r<=0.6): res.append(A)
   elif(r>0.7): res.append(B)
   elif(r>0.6 and r<=0.7): res.append(C)
```

Comment: A tiny corner case, but if r was either exactly 0.6 or .7 your if..elif ladder would have done nothing. I added "<=" signs.

Comment: *r* will never be exactly 0.6, probability of that is formally 0 (although I know what you mean and you are right)

Comment: you could write combined conditions in Python: `0.6 <= r < 0.7` e.g.: `res.append('A' if r < 0.6 else 'B' if 0.6 <= r < 0.9 else 'C')`