# Runtime of merging two lists in Python

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

Suppose we have two lists `A = [a1, a2, ..., an]`(n elements), and `B = [b1, b2, ..., bm]`(m elements), and we use "+" in Python to merge two lists into one, so

```
C = A + B;
```

My question is what the runtime of this operation is? My first guess is `O(n+m)`, not sure if Python is smarter than that.

Comment: Addition of two lists *will* be O(n+m) because each Python list is implemented as a fixed-size C array. When you add two lists, you are allocating memory for a new array and copying each element of each member list into the array. Using append() and extend() will improve performance to O(m), but if you *must* create a third list and preserve the original two, there's no obvious way to improve on O(n+m).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you concatenate the two lists with `A + B`, you create a completely new list in memory. This means your guess is correct: the complexity is `O(n + m)` (where `n` and `m` are the lengths of the lists) since Python has to walk both lists in turn to build the new list.

You can see this happening in the `list_concat` function in the [source code for Python lists](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/listobject.c#L470-L507):

```C
static PyObject *
list_concat(PyListObject *a, PyObject *bb)
{
/* ...code snipped... */
    src = a->ob_item;
    dest = np->ob_item;
    for (i = 0; i < Py_SIZE(a); i++) {     /* walking list a */
        PyObject *v = src[i];
        Py_INCREF(v);
        dest[i] = v;
    }
    src = b->ob_item;
    dest = np->ob_item + Py_SIZE(a);
    for (i = 0; i < Py_SIZE(b); i++) {     /* walking list b */
        PyObject *v = src[i];
        Py_INCREF(v);
        dest[i] = v;
    }
/* ...code snipped... */
```

If you don't need a new list in memory, it's often a good idea to take advantage of the fact that lists are mutable (and this is where Python *is* smart). Using `A.extend(B)` is `O(m)` in complexity meaning that you avoid the overhead of copying list `a`.

The complexity of various list operations are listed [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on the Python wiki.

Answer (score 2):

> My first guess is `O(n+m)`, not sure if Python is smarter than that.

*Nothing* can be smarter than that while returning a *copy*. Though even if `A`, `B`  were immutable sequences such as strings; CPython still makes a full copy instead of aliasing the same memory (it simplifies implementation of the garbage collection for such strings).

In some specific cases, the operation could be `O(1)` depending on what you want to do with the result e.g., `itertools.chain(A, B)` allows to iterate over all items (it does not make a copy, the change in `A`, `B` affects yielded items). Or if you need a random access; you could emulate it using a `Sequence` subclass e.g., [`WeightedPopulation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052108/4279) but in the general case the copy and therefore `O(n+m)` runtime is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

Copying a list is `O(n)` (with `n` being the number of elements) and extending is `O(k)` (with `k` being the number of elements in the second list).  Based on these two facts, I would think it couldn't be any less than `O(n+k)`, since this is a copy and extend operation, and the very least you would need to copy all the elements of both lists.

Source: [Python TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)