# Generating Random Number from Histograms

Tags: random

I need to generate a random number from the following data:

0-10 : 23%

10-80 : 50%

80-100 : 27%

How do I generate a random number from such information?

One way would be to fit a distribution but I have to do this for about hundred variables and I don't want to fit 100 distributions. Any hints?

```
import random
a=[23, 73, 100]
b=[10, 80, 100]
rndval=awesomefunction(a,b)
```

Now, regarding `awesomefunction()`, I have absolutely no clue.

But, from what little I know, (and a very sloppy implementation)

```
temp_rand=random.uniform(0,100)
if(temp_rand<=23):
 rndval=random.uniform(0,10)
if(temp_rand<=73 && temp_rand>23):
 rndval=random.uniform(10,80)
if(temp_rand>73):
 rndval=random.uniform(80,100)
```

But IMHO, this is sloppy beyond measure.

Comment: What language? what code have you tried atleast share all that

Comment: @Mr.Alien, I am language agnostic at the moment but I'll share what I think should be the framework.

Comment: This will probably have to run in O(n^2) time. The most efficient way of doing this is still the same idea, but you can optimize if the inputs are in arrays. You can have nested for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have 2 random generators to achieve this. The first should generate a random double from 0 to 1.

For this generator, you should check to see if the random number is from 0 to .22, .23 to .73, or .74 to 1. If the number falls within the first range, you just run another random number generator that generates a number from 0 to 10, and that's your number. The same goes for the second and third ranges.

Some high level pseudocode:

```
double firstRandomNumber = generateRandomNumberFromZeroToOne();
if (firstRandomNumber <= .22) {
    //generate random number from 0 to 10 and that's your number.
} else if (firstRandomNumber <= .73) {
    //generate random number from 10 to 80 and that's your number.
} else {
    //generate random number from 80 to 100 and that's your number.
}
```

A side note: Most languages already have random number generators that will generate a random number from 0 to 1 or an integer up to a specific range (0 to 10).

Comment: That's the same algorithm that was in the question, right?

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/ and 
[Data structure for loaded dice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027757/data-structure-for-loaded-dice) for information about several approaches, trading speed and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a two-step random fetch. The first random number would tell you which quartile (roughly) to use. Then randomly pull from that group.

Pseudocode:

```
randPercentile = 100 * Rand()

if (randPercentile <= 23)
    randResult = Rand(0, 23)
else if (randPercentile > 23 && randPercentile <= 73)
    randResult = Rand(24, 73)
else
    randResult = Rand(74, 100)

print randResult
```

You have to check the Rand API for your language/framework of choice but most Rand functions will return a float between 0 and 1 by default with overloads for minimum/maximum value ranges. And the latter call (with min/max) can be coded by you pretty easily if it's not available.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought, is this "sloppy" by industry standard?

Comment: The pseudo code example is "sloppy" because it's hardcoded for your ranges. To make it cleaner and reusable I you could modify the code to enable different ranges.

Comment: Is there any way to make this invariant of the total number of "buckets"? For instance, if I had 10 buckets instead of 3 (0-10, 11-20 etc.) would I have to write 10 if loops?

Comment: Yes, see my previous comment. The best way to do it will vary with, again, your language of choice, but you will certainly pass some sort of collection of range data which the Rand algorithm would work against.

Comment: I have added my prospective code to the question (the way I thought of it). But if I had more buckets, I don't think there is a way around writing more if loops. I can probably use switch case but that's that?

Comment: @Inquest: As a separate answer I posted a working C# code snippet that demonstrates an N-range method for generating numbers. It will translate to Java easily and Python (and many other languages) pretty simply as well.

Answer (score 0):

C# implementation of a "ranging" random number generator with N ranges possible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var ranges = new List<Range>
        {
            new Range( 0,  23,  0,  10),
            new Range(24,  73, 11,  80),
            new Range(74, 100, 81, 100),
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            var randInt = GetRand(0, 100, ranges);
            Console.WriteLine(randInt);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Random _myRandom = new Random();

    static int GetRand(int absMin, int absMax, List<Range> ranges)
    {
        var i = _myRandom.Next(absMin, absMax);

        foreach (var range in ranges)
        {
            if (i >= range.PercentMin && i <= range.PercentMax)
            {
                return _myRandom.Next(range.ValueMin, range.ValueMax);
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Incomplete range?");
    }
}

class Range
{
    public int PercentMin { get; set; }
    public int PercentMax { get; set; }
    public int ValueMin { get; set; }
    public int ValueMax { get; set; }

    public Range(int pctMin, int pctMax, int min, int max)
    {
        PercentMin = pctMin;
        PercentMax = pctMax;
        ValueMin = min;
        ValueMax = max;
    }
}
```