# Returning a set using the Vose alias method

Tags: algorithm, math, random, probability

I'm trying to wrap my head around adapting the Vose (aka Walker?) alias method for sampling from a discrete distribution, so that it can return a *set* of values. The idea is that there is a second-stage sampling that picks one value from the set using a *uniform* random distribution.

The application here is a DNS load balancer, where a list of IP addresses with weights is configured. A query should then return a set of IPs to the client in such a way that over time, each IP is selected with a probability corresponding to its weight -- as if a single sample was taken. The various DNS resolvers involved in the process (OS stub resolver, configured recursor, etc) can be assumed to shuffle the IP set uniformly (although that is not always the case).

I've tried doing a straight forward loop: Repeat the Vose sampling *N* times, where *N* is the number of elements in the list. Then throw away duplicates and return the set to the client. Is this the right way of doing it?

Related links:

- [Data structure for loaded dice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027757/data-structure-for-loaded-dice)
- http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/
- https://github.com/seveibar/vose-alias-python