# Drop Chance in swift

Tags: swift

I recentrly started to work with swift, and me and my Mate are trying to make a Small game to test what we learned..
we made a sort of monster fighting game ,no moving object just clicking on the monster.
So far so good evrything works as it should, got Upgrade to get more Hp or Str to do more damage on the monster, and to get more Hp when it hits back.
that said. i'm made items to the game but i want them to drop by the monster.
made different types and would like to know if anyone knows a code to get a Drop Chance on the Items...
like

```
"Normal" = 73%
"Rare" = 25%
"Legend" = 2%
```

I Looked around on evry search engine but can't find anything that i need.
Hope to get a reply soon
Thanks.
Greetz Kristof.V

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991198/game-design-theory-loot-drop-chance-spawn-rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a random function [arc4random_uniform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32552511/3140927)

> Returns a random number between 0 and the inserted parameter minus 1.
>
> For example arc4random_uniform(3) may return 0, 1 or 2 but not 3.

You can use it like:

```
let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))

if random < 73 { 
     // drop normal
}
else if random < 73+25 { 
     // drop rare
} else {
     // drop legend
}
```

Comment: thanks alot!
Had an Idee in my head how i wanted it but i realy coulden't figure it out!
This is just what i needed!

Comment: @Kristof.V: Please don't forget to accept an answer. I suggest the one by `Avt` since he had the idea.

Comment: oow sorry diden't know i had to press that,

Comment: I have to say  1000x thanks for replying, got a first working try in my playground of what i wanted.
http://iswift.org/playground?KbK28M

Answer (score 2):

This logic is the same of the answer by *Avt*, just a different implementation.

```
let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))

switch random {
case 0...72: print("Normal")
case 73...97: print("Rare")
case 98...99: print("Legend")
default: fatalError("Wrong number")
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot you guy's!

Answer (score 1):

(*Edited: to include also weapon type as per follow-up question* *[Random number to print array (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667167/random-number-to-print-array-swift?noredirect=1#comment57080354_34667167)*)

As above, use the `arc4random` function. A more complete "Monster" example follows.

---

It could be appropriate to hold different rarity and weapon types as `enum` cases

```
enum Rarities {
    case Normal
    case Rare
    case Legendary
}

enum Weapons {
    case Knife
    case Sword
    case Katana
}
```

Each monster could be an instance of a `Monster` class with it's own specific item and rarity drop rates, initialized when creating the `Monster` object.

```
class Monster {
    var name : String
    var dropRatesRarity = [Rarities:Double]()
    var dropRatesWeapons = [Weapons:Double]()

    init(name: String, dropRatesRarity: [Rarities:Double], dropRatesWeapons: [Weapons:Double]) {
        self.name = name
        var rateSum = dropRatesRarity.values.reduce(0.0, combine: +)
        var dropRatesCumSum = 0.0
        for (k, v) in dropRatesRarity {
            self.dropRatesRarity[k] = v/rateSum + dropRatesCumSum
            dropRatesCumSum += v/rateSum
        }
        rateSum = dropRatesWeapons.values.reduce(0.0, combine: +)
        dropRatesCumSum = 0.0
        for (k, v) in dropRatesWeapons {
            self.dropRatesWeapons[k] = v/rateSum + dropRatesCumSum
            dropRatesCumSum += v/rateSum
        }
    }

    func dropItem() -> (Weapons,Rarities) {
        return (generateItemType(), generateRarity())
    }

    func generateRarity() -> Rarities {
        let random = Double(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
        return dropRatesRarity.filter({ (k, v) in v >= random }).minElement({ $0.1 < $1.1 })?.0 ?? .Normal
    }

    func generateItemType() -> Weapons {
        let random = Double(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
        return dropRatesWeapons.filter({ (k, v) in v >= random }).minElement({ $0.1 < $1.1 })?.0 ?? .Knife
    }
}
```

Example for some `Monster` instance:

```
/* Example */
var myDropRatesRarity = [Rarities:Double]()
myDropRatesRarity[.Normal] = 73 // relative drop rates, needn't sum to 100
myDropRatesRarity[.Rare] = 25
myDropRatesRarity[.Legendary] = 2

var myDropRatesWeapons = [Weapons:Double]()
myDropRatesWeapons[.Knife] = 50
myDropRatesWeapons[.Sword] = 30
myDropRatesWeapons[.Katana] = 20

var myMonster = Monster(name: "Godzilla", dropRatesRarity: myDropRatesRarity, dropRatesWeapons: myDropRatesWeapons)

var myItem = myMonster.dropItem()
print(myMonster.name + " dropped a \(myItem.0) of \(myItem.1) rarity!")
/* "Godzilla dropped a Katana of Normal rarity!" */
/* ... most likely Normal rarity ... keep grinding! */
```