# Cython multinomial distribution

Tags: python, numpy, random, cython

What is the most efficient way to get a multinomial distribution (say for n=1 trial) in cython?

For example, I have three probabilities p0=0.1, p1=0.2, p2=0.7 (which sum to 1) and want to have x to be 0, 1, 2 with probability p0, p1, p2 respectively.

I tried

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

# the data types
cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] p
cdef int x

rng = np.random.default_rng() # the random number generator from numpy
p = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.7]) # the probabilities
x = <int>(rng.multinomial(1, p, size=1).argmax(axis=-1)[0])
```

But this is very slow, since it has to use a lot of python code. Is there a faster way, which used a good random number generator?

(Side note: I use `multinomial` instead of `choice` from numpy since it has the issue of p only almost summing up to 1 due to rounding errors fixed.)

Comment: This doesnt seem to be a multinomial but rather a choice from 3 with given probability. Abit different from multinom. Try `np.random.choice(range(3), 1, True, p)`

Comment: I had already included a side note on why I am not using `random.choice` - but this is more technical. In general, `random.choice` won't solve the problem at all -- I am looking for an efficient cython solution. With random.choice, we go again pack to numpy. Mathematically, this is a multinomial distribution with n=1 sample

Comment: 1 sample for multinomial should give you something like `[0,0,1]` and not a number/integer. If the sample size = 10 for example, sampling one will give you `[1,2,7]`, meaning for 2 samples you can have `[1,3,6], [0,2,8]` etc. In your case you are just getting an integer

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027757/data-structures-for-loaded-dice/63166311  This is not intended to answer your question, but to show you that there are many ways to do a weighted choice, some of which don't rely on floating-point numbers.  For example, you can assign weights 1, 2, and 7 instead of probabilities 0.1, 0.2, 0.7 which might be rounded in a binary floating-point format.

Comment: Thanks, I will incorporate this in my approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is based on (1) implementing a Bernoulli trial (2) nesting those trials. In this example, I do it for 4 probabilities. As suggested by @peter-o, I use weights instead of probabilities in the arguments.

I am open to better suggestions / improvements.

```
from libc.stdlib cimport rand,srand, RAND_MAX

# this does a bernoulli trial. 
#   output 0 w/ pr l_0/(l_0+l_1)
#   output 1 w/ pr l_1/(l_0+l_1)
cpdef int multinomial2(int l_0,int l_1):
    cdef int draw
    cdef double nom
    cdef double denom
    cdef double factor = (l_0+l_1)/<double>(l_0)
    nom = rand()
    denom = RAND_MAX 
    draw = <int>(nom*1.0/denom *factor)
    print(draw)
    if(draw<1):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

# nest bernoulli trials
cpdef int multinomial4(int l_0,int l_1,int l_2,int l_3):
    cdef int x1
    cdef int ret

    if(multinomial2(l_0+l_1,l_2+l_3)==0):
        if(multinomial2(l_0,l_1)==0):
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
    else:
        if(multinomial2(l_2,l_3)==0):
            return 2
        else:
            return 3
```

**Add-on:** A useful helper function to seed the random number generator:

```
# seed the rng
cpdef void rand_seed(int seed):
    srand(seed)
```