# Python: Select Item from Object List Based on Probability

Tags: python, list, class, probability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weighted random selection with and without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352670/weighted-random-selection-with-and-without-replacement)

I have a long object list of items. I want to randomly select an item from the list based on the probability. The list looks like the following:

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self, pid, hits, qtyPerOrder):
    self.pid = pid
    self.bay = hits
    self.qtyPerOrder = int(qtyPerOrder)

itemList = [('RGSCAF', 181  ,6), ('WAR10227', 54    ,3), ('AD2020WOC', 31   ,4)]
```

Basically, I want a function that will go through the list, assign probability weights based on hits, then randomly choose n number of objects based on the probability. So in this example, there would be a higher probability that the object ('RGSCAF', 181 ,6) is returned since it has the highest hits value.

Comment: Another probable dupe: [How to do weighted random sample of categories in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6432499)

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest solution but it gets the point across:

```
def getNWeightedRandoms(n):
    retval = []
    for x in xrange(0,n):
        retval.append(weightedRandom())
    return retval

def weightedRandom():
    sum = 0
    for item in itemList:
        sum += item.bay
    i = random.randint(0,sum-1)
    for item in itemList:
        i -= item.bay
        if i<0:
            return item
```

Comment: This doesn't return a sample of size `n`, only one item is picked.

Comment: Added function to call weightedRandom n times.

Comment: That method allows for duplicates, I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: the getNWeightedRandoms(n) seems to run an infinite loop

Comment: It's probably just taking a long time because it's O(N*M) where M is the size of the list.  You can speed it up by storing the cumulative hits for each item (e.g. item 2 has cumhits equal to 0.hits + 1.hits + 2.hits), then using bisect instead of a for loop in weighedRandom.