# Implementation of drawing from a set with non-uniform weights

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic

I would like to discuss how to optimally implement the following:

Given a set of elements,

all of them are distinct. Call this input set `N`, it has size `n`. These element each have a weight. Now, you need to create a subset (`R`) of this `N` of size `r`, where `r` is smaller then or equal to `n`.
This subset, again, cannot contain repetitions. Every element of `R` needs to be randomly chosen from `N`, if an element has a higher weight, the chance of it being chosen needs to be higher. If the total weight of all element in `N` is `W`, then the chance that element `i` is chosen needs to be `w_i/W`.

One last detail is that the weights are prone to change, but only to increase, they cannot decrease.

I want a neat implementation for this. I am working in Java, but I am hoping to find some language agnostic properties or details (or even pseudo code) that are interesting.

Now, for my own solution: I create an `Array List` of the original set of elements. I make sure that the weights are natural numbers and I add them `n` times if the weight of the element is `n`. Then I shuffle the arraylist (`collections.shuffle`) and I keep on taking element from the shuffled list and adding them to a Java `Set` until the size of the set is `r`. If the weight of an element increases, it gets added some more times to the original array list. Shuffle again, make a new subset.

My implementation needs loads of memory and the shuffle thingy is also slower if the set becomes bigger. Is there a better idea out there?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's simplify it to drawing only one element, you calcualte

```
sum[-1] = 0
sum[i] = sum[i-1] + weight[i]
```

Then, you simply draw a number `r` in range `[0,sum)`, and do binary search for `r`. The range it falls on, is the number you draw.

This is `O(n)` time solution.

You can obviously do it for more elements, but you will have to remove elements you have chosen from the set, or to repeat until you chose a new item. Both solutions however decay to quadric complexity for large subset size :(

But, can we improve it to do better?

Yes. Use a binary search tree instead of array. The binary search tree is actually a variation of [order statistics tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), where instead of storing `#children(v)`, you store the sum of weights in each subtree. Other than that - that's basically remains the same as order statistics tree.

More information about the tree solution can be found as an answer to a similar question: [Algorithm to shuffle an Array randomly based on different weights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973058/572670)

Complexity of building the tree is `O(nlogn)`, and each query + removal is `O(logn)`, which gives you `O(nlogn + klogn) = O(nlogn)`

So, we have two options:

If `k` in `o(logn)` ([little o](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html) here), prefer recreating array with `O(n)` time per each query. Otherwise, you should prefer (in terms of time complexity) `O(nlogn)` tree based solution.

In terms of space, both solutions are linear in amount of extra space needed.

---

This can be even done better, with a single pass. This is called [weighted reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Weighted_Random_Sampling_using_Reservoir). It's main drawback is instability due to numeric issues for large weights due to the exponent part (at least from my experience).

This solution runs in linear time, with `O(1)` extra space (if not including the output array of size `k`).